# Use Indexes For Join on Indexed DATETIME and Indexed DATE columns

Tags: mysql, sql

EDIT

I misread my initial error and blamed the INDEX not being used on the wrong columns.

I was able to recreate the issue that I saw and the solution that ysth suggested worked.

Below are the create tables statements, inserts to the tables, and two queries - one that has the error and another with the solution which does not have it.

```
# Make tables and indices
DROP TABLE a;
DROP TABLE b;

create table a
(
    DT  DATE,
    USER INT,
    COMMENT_SENTIMENT INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (USER, DT));
CREATE INDEX a_DT_USER_IDX ON a (DT,USER);

create table b
(
    id                                int auto_increment primary key,
    DT  DATETIME(6),
    USER mediumtext,
    COMMENT_SENTIMENT INT);
CREATE INDEX b_DT_USER_IDX ON b (DT);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX b_DT_USER ON b (USER(16), DT);

# Insert some dummy data
INSERT INTO a VALUES('2023-01-01', 5, 4);
INSERT INTO b VALUES(NULL, '2023-01-01 00:00:00', 5, 4);

# Explain that shows the issue I was seeing.
EXPLAIN
SELECT *
FROM a
JOIN b
ON a.DT = b.DT
AND a.USER = b.USER;

# Out
# 1,SIMPLE,a,,ALL,"PRIMARY,a_DT_USER_IDX",,,,1,100,
# 1,SIMPLE,b,,ref,"b_DT_USER,b_DT_USER_IDX",b_DT_USER_IDX,9,a.DT,1,100,Using index condition; Using where

[2023-01-24 18:00:14] [HY000][1739] Cannot use ref access on index 'b_DT_USER' due to type or collation conversion on field 'USER'
[2023-01-24 18:00:14] [HY000][1003] /* select#1 */ select `a`.`DT` AS `DT`, `a`.`USER` AS `USER`,`a`.`COMMENT_SENTIMENT` AS `COMMENT_SENTIMENT`,`b`.`id` AS `id`,`b`.`DT` AS `DT`,`b`.`USER` AS `USER`,`b`.`COMMENT_SENTIMENT` AS `COMMENT_SENTIMENT` from `a` join `b` where ((`a`.`DT` = `b`.`DT`) and (`a`.`USER` = `b`.`USER`))


# Explain with the fix ysth suggested
EXPLAIN
SELECT *
FROM a
JOIN b
ON a.DT = b.DT
AND a.USER = CAST(b.USER AS DECIMAL );

# 1,SIMPLE,a,,ALL,"PRIMARY,a_DT_USER_IDX",,,,1,100,
# 1,SIMPLE,b,,ref,b_DT_USER_IDX,b_DT_USER_IDX,9,a.DT,1,100,Using index condition; Using where

# [2023-01-24 18:04:24] [HY000][1003] /* select#1 */ select `a`.`DT` AS `DT`,`a`.`USER` AS `USER`,`a`.`COMMENT_SENTIMENT` AS `COMMENT_SENTIMENT`,`b`.`id` AS `id`,`b`.`DT` AS `DT`,`b`.`USER` AS `USER`,`b`.`COMMENT_SENTIMENT` AS `COMMENT_SENTIMENT` from `a` join `b` where ((`a`.`DT` = `b`.`DT`) and (`a`.`USER` = cast(`b`.`USER` as decimal(10,0))))
# [2023-01-24 18:04:24] 2 rows retrieved starting from 1 in 359 ms (execution: 250 ms, fetching: 109 ms)
```

__

**The below information is incorrect. Please use the edit to see the issue I was having and it's solution.**

I have three tables `a`, `b`, and `c` in my MySQL 5.7 database. `SHOW CREATE` statements for each table are:

```
CREATE TABLE `a` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `DT` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `USER` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `COMMENT_SENTIMENT` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `a_DT_USER_IDX` (`DT`,`USER`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

```
CREATE TABLE `b` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `DT` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `USER` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `COMMENT_SENTIMENT` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `b_DT_USER_IDX` (`DT`,`USER`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

```
CREATE TABLE `c` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `DT` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `USER` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `COMMENT_SENTIMENT` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `b_DT_USER_IDX` (`DT`,`USER`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Table `a` has a `DATE` column `a.DT`, table `b` has a `DATETIME` column `b.DT`, and table `c` has a `DATE` column `c.DT`.

All of these DT columns are indexed.

As a caveat, while `b.DT` is a `DATETIME`, all of the 'time' portions in it are `00:00:00` and they always will be. It probably should be a `DATE`, but I cannot change it.

I want to join table `a` and table `b` on their DT columns, but explain tells me that their indices are not used:

`Cannot use ref access on index 'b.DT_datetime_index' due to type or collation conversion on field 'DT'`

When I join table `a` and `b` on `a.DT` and `b.DT`

```
SELECT *
FROM a
JOIN b
ON a.DT = b.DT;
```

The result is much slower than when I do the same with a and c

```
SELECT *
FROM a
JOIN c
ON a.DT = c.DT;
```

Is there a way to use the indices in join from the first query on `a.DT = b.DT`, specifically without altering the tables? I'm not sure if `b.DT` having only `00:00:00` for the time portion could be relevant in a solution.

The end goal is a faster select using this join.

Thank you!

-- What I've done section --

I compared the joins between `a.DT = b.DT` and `a.DT = c.DT`, and saw the time difference.
I also tried wrapping `b`'s `DT` column with `DATE(b.DT)`, but explain gave the same issue, which is pretty expected.

Comment: Please show the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for your tables.

Comment: MySQL can't use an index to compare `DATE` and `DATETIME` values. Even though all the values of the datetime have `00:00:00` times, it won't use it.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I wasn't sure if the fact that all of the values had `00:00:00` in them would allow for some lenience.

I appreciate the help!

Comment: Why are you using `DATETIME` if the time is never used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to read a and join b rows, you can just do

```
SELECT *
FROM a
JOIN b
ON b.DT = timestamp(a.DT);
```

If the other way around, then

```
SELECT *
FROM b
JOIN a
ON a.DT = date(b.DT);
```

No need for a virtual column.

Comment: I've already tried the second query - `EXPLAIN` shows the same issue as without the `DATE(b.DT)`.

I just tried the first query, and `EXPLAIN` again says that the index cannot be used.

Comment: Could you edit your question to actually show create table b output and the exact explain you are doing and its output?  What you show doesn't include DT_datetime_index

Comment: I didn't want to show my real tables, so I used a toy set of tables. 

It looks like the real issue is that `a.user` is `int` and `b.user` is `mediumtext`. 

I misread the explain and thought the `DT` columns were not using their indices. 

The query I was having issues with looks like

`SELECT * FROM a JOIN b ON a.DT = b.DT AND a.USER = b.USER`
and the explain was yelling about the `USER` column joins.

Comment: Then just like with date/datetime you need to cast the value from the table you join from to the type (including collation) of the table you join to

Comment: I just tried that and it did work, thank you! I have edited the post to recreate the actual issue and the fix you suggested.

Comment: Please provide the `EXPLAINs`.  One thing I want to see is whether the Optimizer picked `b` as the 'first' table.

Comment: yes, as @RickJames says, join order is important.  if it chooses to join b from a instead of the other way around, it may only use the DT part of the index

Comment: Like I said in the edit, the issue was actually the `USER` joins, the DT portion of the joins actually always used the index.

I have however posted the explains.

Comment: it looks like it is using only the DT part of the index (though I can't make sense of a key length of 9).  either do `FROM b JOIN a` (and check that the optimizer actually does use that order) or do `AND b.USER=concat(a.USER)`.  you want to match the type of the table you are joining *to*

Comment: @ysth - `datetime(6)` = 5 for datetime + 3 for microseconds + 1 for nullable.

Comment: oh, was looking at the show create table (which are for the initial question, not the revised question)

Answer (score 1):

MySQL won't use an index to join `DATE` and `DATETIME` columns.

You can create a virtual column with the corresponding `DATE` and use that.

```
CREATE TABLE `b` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `DT` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `USER` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `COMMENT_SENTIMENT` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DT_DATE` DATE AS (DATE(DT)),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `b_DT_USER_IDX` (`DT_DATE`,`USER`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

SELECT *
FROM a
JOIN b
ON a.DT = b.DT_DATE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Virtually any function call is "not [*sargable*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) "  That is, `CAST(b.USER AS DECIMAL )` prevents the use of an index.

Do not mix strings and ints in comparisons.  The string will be converted to numeric.  If the string is a literal, such as `'123'` then the Optimizer is smart enough to do that once.  If it is a column name, it must check every row.

Tip:  If you are likely to test for *one* `user` and a `range` of dates, then this works better than the opposite order.

```
 INDEX(user, dt)`
```

(You may need an index starting with dt for other queries.)